# In a matrix having a row of zeros, how do I replace the corresponding diagonal entry of the matrix with a one?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a square matrix, A, whose values are zero or one and that contains one or more rows of
zeros. For each row of zeros, I wish to replace the corresponding diagonal entry of A with a one.

For example, suppose

```
A=np.array([[0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

for which rows 3 and 5 are all zeros. I wish to set A[3,3] and A[5,5] equal to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is:

```
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

We can find out the sum of all the rows:

```
>>> A.sum(axis=1)
array([3, 3, 0, 1, 0])
```

We want all the diagonals corresponding to 0-sum rows to be set to 1.

Thus, the following works:

```
>>> row_sums = A.sum(axis=1)
>>> A[row_sums == 0, row_sums == 0] = 1
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Note that this works because `row_sums == 0` is `True` for the desired rows:

```
>>> row_sums == 0
array([False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

and thus `A[row_sums == 0, row_sums == 0]` selects the required elements.